# Failed to Compile. ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a problem....

My project is based in: I have an API and get the value of the JSON, tract with the Axios, and I insert in the variable `peoples` and step to `filtered`, but are giving this error:

> ./src/App.js
>        Line 16:  'peoples' is not defined  no-undef
>       Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Someone know why ?

My code:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.state = {
      elementsPerPage: 3,
      currentPage: 0,
      input: "",
      peoples:[],
      filtered: peoples,
      validate: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:80/people').then(response => {
      this.setState({peoples: response.data});
  }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e.response);
  });
}
```

Comment: you have a `peoples` property, but no `peoples` variable.

Comment: @DanielA.White How I can to write it as variable?

Comment: You need to assign `peoples` first, on top of the component, you can declare `let peoples`.

Comment: Thank you guys, the problem already was resolved!! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference any property of an object while you're still in the process of creating that object. Define `peoples` outside if you want to assign it to both properties:

```
const peoples = [];
this.state = {
  elementsPerPage: 3,
  currentPage: 0,
  input: "",
  peoples,
  filtered: peoples,
```

But are you *sure* that's what you want? Both properties will reference the exact same object in memory. I would guess that you *probably* want a separate array for each property:

```
this.state = {
  elementsPerPage: 3,
  currentPage: 0,
  input: "",
  peoples: [],
  filtered: [],
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,I understood but how i can to insert the value treated by Axios her?

Comment: `filtered` and `peoples` contain the same values?

Comment: @Jota What are you actually trying to do there? Why have properties referencing the same thing? If you had to, you could do `this.setState({ peoples: response.data, filtered: response.data });` but that's pretty silly.

Comment: NICEEEEEE, it was this that i would want <3

Comment: It is because, `peoples` is the variable where not undergo change, already the `filtered` that udergo the changes..

Comment: @Jota Both `peoples` and `filtered` reference the same internal object in memory though - if you mutate `peoples`, you'll mutate `filtered`. Better to make a copy